# Set chmod for full path in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, function, path, chmod

**I have input path:** /var/www/site.com/1/2/3/4/file.php

**I want to:** set chmod 755 on each element after /var/www/site.com/

**e.g. do that by universal algorithm:**

```
chmod ('/var/www/site.com/1/', 0755);
chmod ('/var/www/site.com/1/2/', 0755);
chmod ('/var/www/site.com/1/2/3/', 0755);
chmod ('/var/www/site.com/1/2/3/4/', 0755);
chmod ('/var/www/site.com/1/2/3/4/file.php', 0755);
```

Can you help me, Please?

**P.S.:** Just only chmod full path, not recursive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function chmod_path($base, $path, $perm) {
    $full_path = $base;
    foreach (explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path) as $dentry) {
        $full_path .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$dentry;
        chmod($full_path, $perm);
    }
}

chmod_path('/var/www/site.com', '1/2/3/4/file.php', 0755);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks You Very Much, Greg! It's Absolutely Right. :)